# Doesn't work wi-fi (ubuntu 16.04.3, Asus UX530UX-FY033T)

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, asus

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:ef100000-ef101fff

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

It seems i haven't drivers, I tried updating to kernel 4.14 etc... it all doesn't help me.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Bro, you really help me, this command shows that i have old iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode driver but it needs iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode. I downloaded from https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode  place to lib/firmware, it works for me.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If you'd write this as an answer to your question, I'll be happy to upvote it. Others with the same issue that search AU will appreciate it. You might get a bit better performance if you also download and install -23 and -24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
```

This command helped me figured out that I have an old iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode driver but it needs iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode. I downloaded from https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/blob/master/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode place to lib/firmware and everything is fine.